# How to create a temporary jms queue with jboss?

Tags: java, queue, jms

I need to create temporary queues on fly. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your jms Queue/TopicSession object: see [QueueSession javadoc](http://www.j2ee.me/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/jms/QueueSession.html).

You need to keep the session open for the lifecycle of the temporary queue.

Typical usage is for a client to open a session and put a message on a shared processing queue,using the temporary queue in the reply-to field of the message. eg:(pseudo-code)

```
Queue queue = session.createQueue("shared");
Queue responseQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
Message message = session.createMessage();
message.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
...
session.commit();
...
MessageConsumer responseConsumer = session.createConsumer(responseQueue);
Message response = responseConsumer.receive();
...
session.close();
```

The MDB ( or listener that read the shared process queue ) will send the response back to the reply-to queue. If the client is dead for any reason, its session is closed and the queue ceased to exist.

Comment: Thanx, this was correct answer to my  question, but I needed different solution. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587231/how-to-create-a-temporary-jms-queue-and-connect-to-it-by-name