# How to create a temporary jms queue and connect to it by name?

Tags: java, queue, jms

I need to create a temporary queue for responses, but I need to know if it is possible to connect to temporary queue without sending response queue object via setJMSReplyTo method of message, because replying thread doesn't get that object at all.

Comment: Better post your answer as a real answer and accept it. Otherwise your question will always be in "Unanswered" category and that will confuse as it is really answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I binded my temporary queue to jndi by using InitialContext object, so that I can lookup my temporary queue from thread that needs to use my temporary queue.

```
jndiContext = new InitialContext();
connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
temporaryQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();       
jndiContext.bind(queueJndiName, temporaryQueue);    
destination = temporaryQueue;
responseConsumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
responseConsumer.setMessageListener(new MyListener());
```

To get temporary queue you just need to lookup it in code where you need to use it:

```
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
queue = (Queue) jndiContext.lookup(youTemporaryQueueName);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
asadmin> create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.ConnectionFactory --description "connection factory for XXX" jms/ConnectionFactory



asadmin> create-jms-resource --restype javax.jms.ConnectionFactory --description "connection factory for durable subscriptions"
 --property ClientId=MyID jms/DurableConnectionFactory
```

Command create-jms-resource executed successfully.

as in glassfish server.it will be create successfully.