# Consume jms message when I want

Tags: java, queue, jms

I want to send a message to queue without consumer or with an inactive consumer. And messages are consumed (read) later. Below I show what looks like my idea.

The code which send the message to the queue

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/JmsXA")
private QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory;

@Resource(mappedName = "queue/DocumentServiceMessageBeanPlanified")
private Queue documentQueueDestinationPlanified;

...

public anExampleMethod() {
    QueueConnection queueConnection;
    queueConnection = this.queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
    QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageProducer queueSender = queueSession.createSender(this.documentQueueDestinationPlanified);
    Message messagePlanified = queueSession.createMessage();

    // populate message

    queueSender.send(messagePlanified);
    queueSender.close();
    queueSession.close();
    queueConnection.close();
}
```

The code which read/consume message :

```
public void otherMethod() throws JMSException {
    QueueConnection queueConnection;
    queueConnection = this.queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
    QueueSession queueSession =
        queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    MessageConsumer queueConsumer =
        queueSession.createConsumer(this.documentQueueDestinationPlanified);

    Message aMessage = queueConsumer.receiveNoWait();
    while (aMessage != null) {
        aMessage.acknowledge();

        // some work here with message informations

        aMessage = queueConsumer.receiveNoWait();
    }

    queueConsumer.close();
    queueSession.close();
    queueConnection.close();
}
```

The otherMethod has to be launch only at special moment. Is there a special configuration to do? Because I get this error :

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject jndi dependency: env/com.sylob.cochise.dm1.ejb.entite.document.DocumentServiceBean/documentQueueDestinationPlanified into property com.sylob.cochise.dm1.ejb.entite.document.DocumentServiceBean.documentQueueDestinationPlanified: DocumentServiceMessageBeanPlanified not bound
// do you want all the stack trace?
```

I already use some message queue but with messagedrivenbean or here I need to read at special moment messages :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the queue is persistent the general idea seems reasonable. I can see no obvious error in your code and the error message points to a configuration issue. It seems to ignore your mappedName definition. Application servers are not required to handle mappedName consistently. Perhaps your server ignores it. Try the same annotations with only the sending method or with an MDB and see if that works, also try a JNDI browser or a manual lookup with the mapped name and see if you can resolve the entries that way. I bet that a manual lookup will work (though injection is nicer, of course)!

In addition it would help to know what application server you are using?

Comment: thanks for your reply. **Only first code** change anything. **With MDB** No such error, queue destination is recognized but message is read istantly by the MDB class so there is no longer message when I execute the "otherMethod". Manual lookup? Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587231/how-to-create-a-temporary-jms-queue-and-connect-to-it-by-name)? I'm not sure because I forgot to mention that error is, when I start the server (JBoss 4.x). PS : Maybe I don't understand very well this solution.

Comment: Yes, like the lookup in that example. You can inject the context and call lookup manually. However, you must know where in the JNDI tree you have mapped the queue. A JNDI explorer can help with that if you don't know. By the way, you have created a persistent queue somewhere that you are using, right? If the queue is created automagically by JBoss for you then it might not be persistent and it may need an MDB in order to be created.

Comment: I will try the lookup solution in last option because it's not in the strict rules of the development application. The queue is created by JBoss. And if I do a MDB I have an error too but a MDB which implements MessageListener works. It works but I have to implements onMessage method which consume message :(

Comment: JBoss apparently creates temporary queues dynamically for MDB:s, but that is not what you want. You want to create it in advance and keep it when the server is restarted, don't you? Se [Getting Started with JBoss 4.0](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v5/html/mdb.html). It describes the auto-creation, but then moves on to describe how you can create the queue in advance using a config file or the JMX console. Do that and hopefully your original code works!

Comment: This was perfect! I thank you a lot. I just need to add 'queueConnection.start()' to making that work on my code!